# Asterisk get list of existing channels

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to find a list of available channels.

What I need is this:

```
exten=>s,n,ChanIsAvail(a,b,c,d)
```

The problem is, I don't know where to find a,b,c, etc.  (e.g. "DAHDI/1&DAHDI/2&...")

Are they defined in a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  All your phones and trunk channels are defined in configuration files for Asterisk.

If you are using a GUI like FreePBX, they will be visible from the GUI/ configuration database that is used to create the plain-text Asterisk config files.

The Asterisk config files you'll want to get familiar with are dahdi.conf, sip.conf and iax.conf ... that should have everything you need there.